# Changes in React render function not reflecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is rather simple:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          hello {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {marked(this.props.children.toString())}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
     <div className="commentList">
        <Comment author="John">Here is my comment</Comment>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

My edits to `Comment` don't take effect. However, if I change the name of the var from `Comment` to say `CommentB`, the changes take effect.

**Edit**
My html is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="/js/editor.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am running a local google app engine on `python27` and `webapp2` with `jinja` templating engine.

What gives?

Comment: What do you mean by 'edits'? You haven't defined an edit interface for comment anywhere, like no `onInput` handlers or anything. Nor do you ever pass anything to the `children` props.

Comment: I run your code here and everything looks okay... https://jsfiddle.net/rtkhanas/dh2v353o/
Or something is wrong?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan By edits, I meant if I change the `render()` function to return some other string, and hit refresh on the browser, the html output does not change.

Comment: @RostyslavKhanas You're right, the jsfiddle seems to work fine but my local setup does not. I have edited the question with the rest of the code and my local setup details. Is there something obviously wrong that stands out?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Looks like OP is passing a textnode 'Here is my comment' as a child to the `<Comment>` component. Which is IMHO somewhat odd, but apparently works. Have you adding `console.log()` to your edit, to verify that the new version reaches your browser through google app engine etc?

Comment: @wintvelt I am following Facebook's (React tutorial)[https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html] where they do pass text as children. So text's not the culprit, which I just verified as well. To rule out browser caching, I tried switching browsers in vain. `console.log` confirms that too. I however cloned a fresh server from a different folder which cleared the cache. But then again, once that's cached, it's cached for good. I suppose then this is a Python server issue, not React - the jsfiddle proves that too. I'll dig more & change/close the question accordingly.